# LINQ Query. Linq.Any

Tags: linq, lambda

I have this linq code below converted from a lambda

```
 var train = (from a in db.Certificates
                       where a.Year.Value.Year == year && a.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId
                           && a.IsApproved.Value
                           && a.TrainingSchedules.Any(b => b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                       select a).Distinct();
```

Here is the lambda code from code above

```
    var train = db.Certificates
.Join(db.TrainingSchedules, a => a.CertificateId, b => b.CertificateId, (a, b) => new { a, b })
.Where(x => x.a.Year.Value.Year == year && x.a.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId && x.a.IsApproved.Value && x.b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
.Select(z => z.a).Distinct();
```

My questiion is about the `.Any` I just notice when I tried to convert the lambda query into linq. The `.Any` will be use if the two tables from my database has a relationship?. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Here is the code that i am trying to convert

```
 var reg = db.Registrations
            .Join(db.Employees, a => a.EmployeeId, b => b.EmployeeId, (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Where(c => c.a.ScheduleId.Value == scheduleId && (!c.a.Attended.HasValue || !c.a.Attended.Value))
            .Select(d => d.a);
```

Can i convert it like my `First Code` with the `Any`?. If not please tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: `Any` has nothing to do with relationships. It's like a subquery that checks if a condition is met, in sql it's a `EXISTS`. There don't has to be a relationship(foreign-key) to be able to use `EXISTS`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I try to covert some of the lambda code in my project but the `Any` didn't appear from the intellisense list.

Comment: `Any` isn't supported in query syntax. You have to use method syntax (as you've already done above).